# How do I temporarily skip running the compile task in an custom sbt command?

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to temporarily skip the compile task when running the `package` task from within a `quick-install` command (defined in a sbt plugin I'm writing). I'm able to skip all compiles by putting the `skip` setting on the `compile` task, but that causes all `compile` tasks to be skipped:

```
  object MyPlugin extends Plugin {
    override lazy val settings = Seq(
      (skip in compile) := true
    )
    ...
  }
```

What I need is to only skip the `compile` when running my `quick-install` command. Is there a way to modify a setting temporarily, or to scope it to only my quick-install command?

I've tried a settings transformation (based on https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Advanced-Command-Example), that should replace all instances of `skip := false` with `skip := true`, but it doesn't have any effect (i.e. compiles still occur after the transformation):

```
object SbtQuickInstallPlugin extends Plugin {
  private lazy val installCommand =  Command.args("quick-install", "quick install that skips compile step")(doCommand(Configurations.Compile))

  override lazy val settings = Seq(
    commands ++= Seq(installCommand),
    (Keys.skip in compile) := false    // by default, don't skip compiles
  )

  def doCommand(configs: Configuration*)(state: State, args: Seq[String]): State = {
    val extracted = Project.extract(state)
    import extracted._
    val oldStructure = structure

    val transformedSettings = session.mergeSettings.map(
      s => s.key.key match {
        case skip.key => { skip in s.key.scope := true } // skip compiles
        case _ => s
      }
    )

    // apply transformed settings (in theory)
    val newStructure = Load.reapply(transformedSettings, oldStructure)
    Project.setProject(session, newStructure, state)

    ...
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing and/or a better way to do this?

Edit:

The skip setting is a Task, so an easy fix was to:

```
object SbtQuickInstallPlugin extends Plugin {
  private lazy val installCommand =  Command.args("quick-install", "quick install that skips compile step")(doCommand(Configurations.Compile))

  private var shouldSkipCompile = false  // by default, don't skip compiles

  override lazy val settings = Seq(
    commands ++= Seq(installCommand),
    (Keys.skip in compile) := shouldSkipCompile
  )

  def doCommand(configs: Configuration*)(state: State, args: Seq[String]): State = {
    shouldSkipCompile = true // start skipping compiles

    ... // do stuff that would normally trigger a compile such as running the packageBin task

    shouldSkipCompile = false // stop skipping compiles
  }
}
```

I'm not convinced this is the most robust solution, but it appears to work for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
object SbtQuickInstallPlugin extends Plugin {
  private lazy val installCommand =  Command.args("quick-install", "quick install that skips compile step")(doCommand(Configurations.Compile))

  private var shouldSkipCompile = false  // by default, don't skip compiles

  override lazy val settings = Seq(
    commands ++= Seq(installCommand),
    (Keys.skip in compile) := shouldSkipCompile
  )

  def doCommand(configs: Configuration*)(state: State, args: Seq[String]): State = {
    shouldSkipCompile = true // start skipping compiles

    ... // do stuff that would normally trigger a compile such as running the packageBin task

    shouldSkipCompile = false // stop skipping compiles
  }
}
```

Is fine, of course you can go with that!